# Coordinate Invariant Divergence

Tags: general-relativity

I'm reading the book "Einstein Gravity in a nutshell" by Anothy Zee and I'm a bit stuck on one of the steps in the derivation for divergence in an arbitrary coordinate system.  The proof goes as follows,

since we know
$$W^\mu\partial_\mu\phi$$
where $W^\mu$ is a vector field, $\phi$ is a scalar field, and $\partial_\mu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$
and
$$\int\sqrt{g}d^Dx$$
where $g$ is the determinant of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, and $d^Dx$ is the integral in D dimensions (e.g. $d^3x=dx^1dx^2dx^3$), transform like scalars.  We invoke the integral
$$I=\int W^\mu\partial_\mu\phi\cdot\sqrt{g}d^Dx$$
which transforms like a scalar.  Integrating by parts,
$$I=W^\mu\phi\sqrt{g}-\int\phi\cdot\partial_\mu\left(W^\mu\sqrt{g}\right)d^Dx$$
However the book does not have the first term.  Why is $W^\mu\phi\sqrt{g}=0$?

One possible explanation that I have come up with is that it transforms like a vector, so in order for the LHS and RHS to be consistent (i.e. transform like a scalar), the first term can only equal zero, but I think this is really pushing it.  What's a better explanation?

Comment: Related: MathSE https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1653805/532409 and PhysSE https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/431877/226902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrated out term is a surface integral
$$
\int W^\mu \phi \sqrt g \,dS_\mu
$$
at infinity (and not what you have written). $\phi$ is arbitrary, and as always in these types of arguments, can be taken to be zero at infinity. So the integrated out term vanishes.

Comment: Thanks!  I was wondering how I can get the $dS_\mu$ from doing the integration by parts?  From multi variable calculus I know that it probably comes from the divergence theorem, and I did think it was weird that it dropped a lower index so the answer makes perfect sense, but the book just says "using integration by parts", which would just give $uv-\int u'vd^Dx$?